# number of permutations of n dissimilar things taken r at a time when k(< r) particular things always occur

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

```
The number of permutations of n dissimilar things 
taken r at a time when k(< r) particular things always 
occur is [(n-k)P(r-k)] .[ rPk].
I cant understand the second part of the formula..[rPk]

What is the permutation of 10 balls taken 6 at a time, 
on the condition two balls that are numbered 1 and 10 must always occur?

8P4 is ok and then there is a possibility of permuting in 6! ways. 
Where i am getting it wrong? I think the answer is [8P4].[6!]

But as per the formula it should be [8P4].[6P2]..
please help me how we get 6P2
```

Comment: I think the notation may be confusing us here.  There's a binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ or $C(n,k)$ for combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time.  Your "`rPk`" notation is something different but related.

Comment: @sorry i cant get u..if you are saying i should not use any [] in it..

Comment: @hardmath feel free to edit the question

Comment: Yes, I will.  I think I've got the idea now.  Let me answer, and then we can edit the question if you see it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is that there are $\dbinom{n-k}{r-k}$ times $r!$ such permulations. Once you have chosen the $r-k$ objects from the $n-k$, to join the $k$ that must be selected, the resulting collection can be lined up in $r!$ different orders.

**Remark** (in response to a question in a comment): In a long list of "types" of problems, the web site mentioned in the comment offers $P(n-k, r-k)P(r,k)$ as the answer to the question.

First we express our answer above in terms of factorials. It is
$$\frac{(n-k)!}{(r-k)!(n-r)!}r!.\tag{$1$}$$

The answer offered in the link, in terms of factorials, 
$$\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-r)!}\cdot \frac{r!}{(r-k)!}.\tag{$2$}$$
Clearly the two answers are the same.

We describe the reasoning behind Formula $(2)$.  Say the $k$ special objects we must take are red, and numbered $1$ to $k$. Suppose the rest of the objects are blue.

Imagine also that our $r$ objects will be placed into $r$ consecutive slots. We grab and line up $r-k$ blue objects from the $n-k$ blue objects available.  This can be done in P(n-k, r-k)$ ways.

Then we make an ordered selection (permutation) of $k$ slots from the $r$ available. The $k$ red objects will be placed in the chosen slots, with red $1$ going into the first slot in the permutation, red $2$ in the second slot in the permutation, and so on. The permutation of $k$ slots chosen from $r$ can be done in $P(r,k)$ ways. Then the empty slots are filled, from left to right,  with our permutation of $r-k$ objects taken from $n-k$. That gives the product described in the link.

A final comment: The list of "types" mentioned is quite long, with a special formula for each type. Presumably one is invited to memorize all of these. I believe that it is much better to have a limited number of basic **strategies** than to try to remember a large number of  "canned" formulas. One develops such strategies by working through many  diverse problems.

Comment: actually i need a clarification. can u give me or modify my problem so that it will fall under the category of using the condition 5 of permutation in this link http://mathematics.learnhub.com/lesson/4623-permutations-and-combinations-basics

Comment: I have given a (lengthy!) explanation of why the formula you linked to also gives the answer. That formula is *correct*. The expression I developed in my answer is also correct: the answers *look* different, but are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$ or sometimes $C(n,r)$ gives the number of combinations of $n$ things taken $r$ at a time, with the formula:

$$ \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} $$

The notation `rPk` or perhaps $P(r,k)$ should instead mean the number of serial arrangements (permutations) of $r$ things taken $k$ at a time, and would have formula:

$$ P(r,k) = \binom{r}{k} k! $$

That is, choose a subset of $k$ from the given $r$ things, then permute those chosen in $k!$ ways.  Simplifying we have:

$$ P(r,k) = \frac{r!}{(r-k)!} $$

Now suppose the problem is as you've described, to restrict the count $P(n,r)$ of permutations of $n$ distinct things taken $r$ at a time to ones that happen to contain a prescribed subset of $k$ specific items.

The purported answer is $P(n-k,r-k)P(r,k)$, and this amounts to:

$$ P(n-k,r-k)P(r,k) = \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-r)!} \frac{r!}{r-k!} $$

As with many combinatorial counting problems, there's more than one way to think about this.  We could ask to choose from the $n-k$ items *not* specified the extra $r-k$ items we need to arrange, which accounts for a factor of $\binom{n-k}{r-k}$, and then multiply that by the $r!$ ways of permuting the combined set of $k$ prescribed items and $r-k$ items that were "freely" chosen:

$$ \binom{n-k}{r-k} r! = \frac{(n-k)!}{(r-k)!(n-r)!} r! $$

Basic algebra shows this agrees with the formula above.  In particular we can understand the example of 10 balls to be permuted 6 at a time, on the condition that balls "1" and "10" are always taken.  There would be $P(8,4) = \frac{8!}{4!}$ ways to permute four balls out of the eight excluding "1" and "10".  Out of the final 6 positions, we can arrange the two special balls "1" and "10" into those slots in $P(6,2) = \frac{6!}{4!}$ ways.  Since the other four balls already have a defined order from our choice of their "permutation", there's a known way to place them into the remaining four empty slots in the final 6 positions, so $P(8,4) P(6,2) = 50400$ is correct.